# Start lad web process failed with sharp.node requires libvips-cpp.42.dylib 49.0.0

Tags: homebrew, vips, sharp

I am following this basic installation guide here

https://github.com/ladjs/lad#installation

My versions are below:

```
crocodile version: 1.0.4
node version: v8.2.1
platform: Darwin Kernel Version 16.6.0: Fri Apr 14 16:21:16 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.60.24~6/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

However when I ran `nodemon lib/web` I got below error:

```
[nodemon] 1.11.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node lib/web lib/web.js`
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.env'
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.env'
raven@1.2.1 alert: no DSN provided, error reporting disabled
debug: will use /Users/myusername/croctest1/src/locales/ar.json
debug: read /Users/myusername/croctest1/src/locales/ar.json for locale: ar
debug: will use /Users/myusername/croctest1/src/locales/bn.json
debug: read /Users/myusername/croctest1/src/locales/bn.json for locale: bn
debug: will use /Users/myusername/croctest1/src/locales/de.json
debug: read /Users/myusername/croctest1/src/locales/de.json for locale: de
debug: will use /Users/myusername/croctest1/src/locales/en.json
debug: read /Users/myusername/croctest1/src/locales/en.json for locale: en
debug: will use /Users/myusername/croctest1/src/locales/es.json
debug: read /Users/myusername/croctest1/src/locales/es.json for locale: es
debug: will use /Users/myusername/croctest1/src/locales/fr.json
debug: read /Users/myusername/croctest1/src/locales/fr.json for locale: fr
debug: will use /Users/myusername/croctest1/src/locales/he.json
debug: read /Users/myusername/croctest1/src/locales/he.json for locale: he
debug: will use /Users/myusername/croctest1/src/locales/hi.json
debug: read /Users/myusername/croctest1/src/locales/hi.json for locale: hi
debug: will use /Users/myusername/croctest1/src/locales/it.json
debug: read /Users/myusername/croctest1/src/locales/it.json for locale: it
debug: will use /Users/myusername/croctest1/src/locales/ja.json
debug: read /Users/myusername/croctest1/src/locales/ja.json for locale: ja
debug: will use /Users/myusername/croctest1/src/locales/pt.json
debug: read /Users/myusername/croctest1/src/locales/pt.json for locale: pt
debug: will use /Users/myusername/croctest1/src/locales/ru.json
debug: read /Users/myusername/croctest1/src/locales/ru.json for locale: ru
debug: will use /Users/myusername/croctest1/src/locales/zh.json
debug: read /Users/myusername/croctest1/src/locales/zh.json for locale: zh
Error: dlopen(/Users/myusername/croctest1/node_modules/sharp/build/Release/sharp.node, 1): Library not loaded: @rpath/libvips-cpp.42.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/myusername/croctest1/node_modules/sharp/build/Release/sharp.node
  Reason: Incompatible library version: sharp.node requires version 49.0.0 or later, but libvips-cpp.42.dylib provides version 48.0.0
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:598:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myusername/croctest1/node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js:8:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myusername/croctest1/node_modules/sharp/lib/index.js:3:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myusername/croctest1/src/app/controllers/web/gigs.js:5:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myusername/croctest1/lib/app/controllers/web/index.js:24:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myusername/croctest1/lib/app/controllers/index.js:8:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myusername/croctest1/src/routes/web/index.js:4:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myusername/croctest1/src/routes/index.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myusername/croctest1/src/web.js:35:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I did all the following but no help:

```
brew update && brew upgrade
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install vips
brew unlink vips && brew link vips
```

Could you please help find issues here? Thanks.

Comment: I would open an issue on the sharp issue tracker, they are very helpful, and github issues are a much better place to debug install problems  https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues

Answer (score 0):

Creator of Lad here...  If you want to join us in Slack or email us we'd be happy to help you figure this out.  Also please note that CrocodileJS has been renamed to Lad, and Lad is now in alpha development at https://ladjs.github.io/lad/.

Community Links: https://github.com/ladjs/lad#community